# Rails 3 - Model Association Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a project where an User can own a Project and make part of a Project as a Team.

My models are like that:

```
class User
 has_many :projects, :foreign_key => "owner_id"
 has_many :project_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
 has_many :shared_projects, :class_name => "Project", :through => :project_memberships, :foreign_key => "member_id"
end

class Project
 belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
 has_many :project_memberships
 has_many :members, :class_name => "User", :through => "project_memberships", :foreign_key => "member_id"
end
```

My question is: How can I create/delete etc a new Project so an User can own it since I'm not using nested resources?

Here is my Project Controller:

```
def new
@project = Project.new
end

def create
@owner = User.find(params[:user_id])
@project= @owner.projects.build(params[:project])   
    ...
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to store current signed in user ID in session or use some authentication gem (like devise) which will do it for you.

Devise provides helper method `current_user` which returns an instance of User model. So you could do like so:

```
def create
@project= current_user.projects.build(params[:project])   
    ...
end
```

**Update**
If you pass user_id through form, you allow anyone to create project with another user's id. Actions that create something, that belong to current user should be constrained to current user on the serverside

Comment: I think I did it already and didn't work out. My form starts with that: `<%= form_for ([@user,@project]) do |f| %>`. Is this wrong? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Actually, I had some problems with `build` method, so I ended up with `Model.create` and passing current_user as an argument for a dirty quick-fix.

Comment: Give some more info on the 'not working' part please. If it's an error, what does it say? If not, what happens?

Comment: I'm able to create a new Project but without the Id from the User.

Comment: Sorted things out the problem was with my database, but with your method all works out. And I used the `build` instead of the `Model.create`. Thanks!